# How to set variable path in Azure Functions with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

Here is my `PowerShell` script that takes back up of `Postgresql server` in remote location.

Also `postgres` is installed in my local PC.

```
Set-Location 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\';
$env:PGPASSWORD = 'MyPassword';
$bkpBaseFolder = 'D:\dbBackup\';
$PGPATH="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe";
$cdate = (Get-Date).ToString('dd-MMM-yy_HH-mm');
$NewFolder = $bkpBaseFolder + $cdate + '\';
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $NewFolder;

$dbs =  .\psql -h mysite.com -U postgres -c 'SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;'

foreach($db in $DBs) {
    $fileName = $NewFolder + $db + '.bkp';
    & $PGPATH -h mysite.com -U postgres -f $fileName -d $db
}
```

I want to move this script to Azure Functions with `Powershell` to run on specified time everyday.

How do I set Path variables of `pg_dump` or other local paths without installing it?

Comment: Suppose this could help you.https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#adding-environment-variables

Comment: I could not get ur suggestion. Please elaborate.

Comment: According to the script you provide, you need to access your on-premise file system. I suggest you host the script on Azure Automation service. With Hybrid Runbook Worker in Automation service, we can directly access your file system : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker

Comment: @JimXu you don't really tell us how that can be done. When running an automation, there is no way to access pg_dump as it's not loaded in the runtime.